# How to use bash's grep in perl?

Tags: perl, grep, wc

I would like to run the following unix command in perl:

```
grep -r "some_word" /path/to/directory | wc -l
```

(The goal is to see how many times does "some_word" appear in a directory and all its inside-folders/files.

What is Perl's equvalence?
I tried looking [here](https://metacpan.org/dist/PerlPowerTools/view/bin/grep), but not enough examples for what I need.

For example, this is what I have:

```
/tmp/a/text1:
"This is a big text"

/tmp/a/text2:
"This is another text"

/tmp/b/text3:
"One more big text"

/tmp/a/a2/text4:
"Last big text"
```

and I would like to be able to run the grep command and I shall get:

```
grep_command_in_perl -r "big" /tmp/ | wc -l
3
```

Thanks! :)

*** EDIT: ***
(I don't understand why the question was closed... What kind of expectation was expected from me? Is "grep -r "some_word" /path/to/directory | wc -l" not enough to understand what I'm asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can count the number of lines matching the word `some_word` in all files in directory `/path/to/directory` and its sub directories recursively. This is the equivalent of `grep -r some_word /path/to/directory | wc -l`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

{
    my $dir = '/path/to/directory';
    my $count = 0;
    my $word = 'some_word';
    find(sub { wanted($_, \$count, $word) }, $dir);
    say $count;
}

sub wanted {
    my ( $fn, $count, $word ) = @_;
    return if !-f $_;
    open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
        $$count++ if $line =~ /$word/;
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

If you want to interpret `$word` literally (escape regex meta characters like `*`, `)`, ..., and so on) use `/\Q$word\E/` instead of `/$word/`